# GWT Popup window in new browser window

Tags: gwt

I am trying to open new pop up window (browser window ) on click of button . Please suggest how to impement it.

Comment: please mark the answer that you found helpful correct.

Answer (score 20):

This should give you the basic idea on how  to do this.

```
    Button openWindow = new Button("Open Window");
    openWindow.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        public void onClick(final ClickEvent clickEvent) {
            Window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", null);
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(openWindow);
```

Comment: This doesn't seam to support keeping access to the state of the application.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Window.open()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) inside a [Button's](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html) ClickHandler should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

We have to use [HTML's Target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute to tell the browser,that where it should open.

```
Window.open("www.google.com","_blank","");
```

From the link

> **_blank**    Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
>
> **_self** Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
>
> **_parent**   Opens the linked document in the parent frame
>
> **_top**  Opens the linked document in the full body of the window