# GWT replacement of window.open with anchor

Tags: gwt, anchor

This question is similar, but i need a replacement for window.open with anchor so that it opens a url on click of the button

**How do i fire the anchor event using a method**

[GWT Popup window in new browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735182/gwt-popup-window-in-new-browser-window)

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? I tried something similar once to get around popup blockers, but I finally found another work around using some JSNI.

Answer (score 0):

To open an `Anchor` in a new window, use the constructor that lets you specify a `target`, and set that target to "_blank"

Comment: @Jason hall how do i fire the anchor event by a method

Comment: You'll need to fire a `ClickEvent` on your anchor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238355/firing-click-event-from-code-in-gwt